# How to change the default credential of hybris data hub

Tags: tomcat, openssl, sap-commerce-cloud, idoc

I have configured data hub with hybris. But I have to change the default password in datahub local.properties from nimda to Hybris123. I've used openssl to encrypt the pwd. While publishing idoc, I am getting the below error.

```
datahub.security.basic.admin.user=admin
datahub.security.basic.admin.password=Hybris123
datahub.security.basic.read_only.user=rouser
datahub.security.basic.read_only.password=ropass

datahub.core.export.service.clientid=eic
datahub.core.export.service.clientsecret=Hybris123
datahub.encryption.key.path= ${catalina.home}/webapps/ROOT/opt/datahub/security-dir/encryption-key.txt

# inbound adapter
datahub.extension.exportURL=http://localhost:9001/datahubadapter
datahub.extension.userName=admin
datahub.extension.password=Hybris123

#Hybris Core
targetsystem.hybriscore.url=http://localhost:9001/datahubadapter
targetsystem.hybriscore.username=admin
targetsystem.hybriscore.password=Hybris123
```

Tomcat log:

> 2017-09-20 16:30:44,639 [DEBUG] [c.h.d.c.c.i.DefaultExportClient] Status of the response from publish to target system: HybrisCore, 200
>
> 2017-09-20 16:30:46,364 [INFO] [c.h.d.s.s.AuthenticationFailureApplicationListener] Received GET request /core-publications/2/Company.txt with user [admin] - Failed authentication caused by org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Hybris log:

> [32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-130-Task [8798452351926]] [ImpexDataImportClient] Response status from http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2: 401
>   [[1;31mERROR [TaskExecutor-master-130-Task [8798452351926]] [ClientRetryListener] Failed to communicate to http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2
>   [m java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to communicate to http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.rest.client.ImpexDataImportClient.returnImportResultWithRetry(ImpexDataImportClient.java:107) ~[datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.rest.client.ImpexDataImportClient.lambda$1(ImpexDataImportClient.java:87) ~[datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263) [spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:154) [spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.rest.client.ImpexDataImportClient.returnImportResult(ImpexDataImportClient.java:86) [datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.facades.impl.DefaultItemImportFacade.callbackToDataHub(DefaultItemImportFacade.java:105) [datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.facades.impl.DefaultItemImportFacade.importItems(DefaultItemImportFacade.java:58) [datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.tasks.ItemImportTaskRunner.run(ItemImportTaskRunner.java:48) [datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.tasks.DefaultDataHubTaskExecutionStrategy.run(DefaultDataHubTaskExecutionStrategy.java:33) [datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.task.impl.DefaultTaskService.processTask(DefaultTaskService.java:1505) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.task.impl.DefaultTaskService.process(DefaultTaskService.java:1409) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.task.impl.DefaultTaskService.processInTenant(DefaultTaskService.java:1378) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.task.impl.DefaultTaskService$5.run(DefaultTaskService.java:1257) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unauthorized response from http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2
>           at com.hybris.datahub.core.rest.client.ImpexDataImportClient.returnImportResultWithRetry(ImpexDataImportClient.java:100) ~[datahubadapterserver.jar:?]
>           ... 15 more
>   [1;31mERROR [TaskExecutor-master-130-Task [8798452351926]] [ClientRetryListener] Caused by: Unauthorized response from http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2.

Comment: Did you change admin password in hybris side?

Comment: yes. I have changed admin's password in backoffice also(User->employees->admin->administration->change pwd).

Comment: May be this answer resolve your issue: https://experts.hybris.com/questions/52476/datahub-user-name-password-issue.html

Answer (score 0):

Authentication url strategy was changed with hybris 6.0.

Can you add this config **datahub.core.export.service.oauth.path = /authorizationserver/oauth/token** in your datahub local.properties file.

```
ERROR [TaskExecutor-master-130-Task [8798452351926]] [ClientRetryListener] Caused by: Unauthorized response from http://localhost:8181/datahub-webapp/v1/core-publications/2.
```